# Is there a way to select a bubble box using Selenium (Python)?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, scrapy

I'm currently trying to do a side project in Python using Selenium and Scrapy that buys something for me automatically without actually actually going on to the website and buying it. The website I am trying to buy the item I want is on Best Buy but I seem to have run into a problem. Everything seems to work except I can't get my program to select or fill in a bubble option.

[Bubble for Shipping or Pickup on Best Buy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzUMD.png)

I want to select the bubble where it says "FREE Shipping to..." but when I run my code the bubble never gets selected.

What I have done so far is I have gone to the cart in Best Buy on Firefox and pressed F12 to pull up the Tool Box. From there I clicked the inspector and grabbed the XPath for the bubble by hovering over it and got this line to be highlighted.  [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vk9SU.png)

The XPath I used is this, `//*[@id="fulfillment-shipping-5ql53wtzjaaz-414vrr5kl4n8v"]`. I have taken a look at how Selenium can grab elements from web pages and click them but I honestly have no idea why this isn't working. I have also tried using different parts around it like clicking the text "Free Shipping to.." but that didn't work either. Here is the code I used for trying to get this to work,

```
# This is a tester for clicking the bubble for "FREE Shipping to..."
print("\nClicking the FREE Shipping Bubble.\n")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='fulfillment-shipping-4rzhc78gzkg6j48qf0um67gltu']").click()
```

If someone could point me in the right direction that would be great.

Comment: Are you sure that the id of the input you are trying to click doesn't change on each page reload ? Both xpaths you provided are not the same and the "4rzhc78gzkg6j48qf0um67gltu" part looks like some kind of user unique id

Comment: I see what your saying. Like if its selected then the Xpath ID would change and be different on the reload? If that is the case then would there even be a way to select it?

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
driver.find_element_by_name("availability-selection").click()
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to select the bubble for "Free Shipping to...". After looking at S.Ferard's comment and seeing how every time I reload to the page the XPath ID changes, I found out that you can use a starts-with method to see if the ID starts-with a certain portion of a specified ID. I ran this, `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[starts-with(@id,'fulfillment-shipping-')]").click()`and got what I was looking for which was for the program to go to my cart on Best Buy, click the bubble for "Free Shipping to..." and then head to checkout.

Answer (score 0):

Use property == fullxpath == in "Chrome browser":

Ex: [image]

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[3]/form/div[3]/button[1]").click()
```